# How to add data of type "date from Excel sheet to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have this code that can insert my Excel rows into a SQL Server table, but it doesn't work with the data of `date` type. In Excel, the data is `2010-02-21` but in the formula bar, it appears as `21/02/2010` (I don't know if makes any change) and in the SQL Server table, I tried `insert values ('2010-02-21')` and it worked that means nothing wrong in SQL Server.

```
Sub InsertNewRowsToSqlServer()
  On Error Resume Next
   
  ' Set up the SQL Server connection
  Dim con As Object
  Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  con.Open "driver={sql server};server=DESKTOP-F3OGEH0\VE_SERVER;database=test;uid=sa;pwd=Cotherm123;"

  ' Check if the connection is successful
  If con.State <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Error connecting to SQL Server.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Specify the Excel data range (starting from A1)
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  Dim lastRow As Long
  lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

  ' Retrieve the maximum value of 'id' in the existing SQL Server table
  Dim maxId As Long
  Dim maxIdSql As String
  maxIdSql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM testyt"
  maxId = con.Execute(maxIdSql).Fields(0).Value

  Dim tableRange As Range
  Set tableRange = ws.Range("A1:D" & lastRow)
   
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 2 To tableRange.Rows.Count
    ' Compare the 'id' value with the maximum existing 'id'
    If tableRange.Cells(i, 1).Value > maxId Then
      ' Use a parameterized query to prevent SQL injection for INSERT
      Dim Sql As String
      Sql = "INSERT INTO testyt (id, name, number, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
       
      Dim cmdInsert As Object
      Set cmdInsert = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
      cmdInsert.ActiveConnection = con
      cmdInsert.CommandText = Sql
      cmdInsert.CommandType = 1 ' adCmdText
      
      ' Bind parameters securely for INSERT
      cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("Param1", 3, 1, , tableRange.Cells(i, 1).Value) ' adInteger, adParamInput
      cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("Param2", 200, 1, 50, tableRange.Cells(i, 2).Value) ' adVarChar, adParamInput
      cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("Param3", 3, 1, , tableRange.Cells(i, 3).Value) ' adInteger, adParamInput

     cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("Param4", 7, 1, , Format(tableRange.Cells(i, 4).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")) ' adDBDate, adParamInput

      ' Execute the INSERT query
      cmdInsert.Execute
    End If
  Next i

  con.Close
  MsgBox "Data added to SQL Server!"
End Sub
```

I get no error, but nothing is added into the SQL Server table

Comment: "but nothing is added in sql table" - do you mean no records are inserted or records are inserted with blank dates ? What happens if you remove the `On Error Resume Next` line.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of using ADODB.Parameter is that you don't need to take care about the format. For dates, you simply pass the value as *date* (not as a string as you do). This works no matter what database system you have in the background and which regional settings you or the db server has - the driver will take care about it.

Assuming that your cell contains a date (and not a string that looks like a date), simply write

```
 cmdInsert.Parameters.Append cmdInsert.CreateParameter("Param4", 7, 1, , tableRange.Cells(i, 4).Value)
```

If you look closely to your code, you do something similar already for the string parameter ("Param2"): When you pass a string, you can omit the (single) quote characters that are needed when having the string inside the SQL command.

Comment: this was the first thing i tried but i still have the same problem, i dont know if it maight be related to the excel table

Comment: Have you tried to write the excel value into a date variable and pass this to the command?